# Get Resources from java class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-resources

```
public String  getDay() {
     if (getDay().equals("Mon")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());
     } else if (getDay().equals("Sun")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     } else if (getDay().equals("Tue")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     } else if (getDay().equals("Wed")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     } else if (getDay().equals("Thu")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     } else if (getDay().equals("Fri")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     } else if (getDay().equals("Sat")){
         int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

     }
     return day;
}
```

I want to convert days of the week to images, example (icon_Mon). The `public String getday` is in another java class not in `MainActivity` I want to get Resources from drawable.

My point is how can I get Resources from another java class?

Comment: There are two ways : 1) Pass `Resources` in method as a parameter. 2) Pass `Context` in method as a parameter and access `Resource` using that context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getResources()` on a context. So either you pass a context to `getDay(Context ctx)` and use it to get the resources. Or you can extend the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and use a static instance of it wherever you need it.